# how to create new scheduled event in amazon aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to create a new scheduled event to reboot an instance every two days, how can I do it?

I have seen the events pane option, but I don't see any option to create a new scheduled event.

Comment: Could you do it as a CRON job?

See:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/13730/how-can-i-schedule-a-nightly-reboot

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to these events:

> AWS can schedule events for your instances, such as a reboot, stop/start, or retirement.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-instances-status-check_sched.html

Those are only scheduled by AWS personnel or systems, and they are only applicable to AWS-initiated maintenance of the systems underlying EC2.

EC2 and AWS overall, does not have a user-initiated event scheduler.

To schedule an instance reboot for your own reasons, either a cron job on the instance itself or an external event-emitting system is needed.

Comment: Thanks Michael, your answer is very verbose.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot Is there a way to request an instance undergoes maintenance, for testing purposes of the scheduled event system? I would like to create a system that responds to these requests and having at least one instance that pops up with a scheduled event would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: @AlexCohen it's unlikely that there's a way to simulate a maintenance event, since those usually impact all the VMs running under the impacted hypervisor.  As far as I know, the emails are the only autonomous notification.  You can, however, get a good idea of what a maintenance event would look like in the API docs for the EC2 [DescribeInstanceStatus](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstanceStatus.html) request.  Note that depending on the event's cause, the instance may already be unresponsive when the event occurs if the failure wasn't proactively detected.

Comment: Yep I already have a few ways of getting info on instances with `scheduled events` using the `DescribeInstanceStatus` request.  Having actual instances with a `scheduled events` is not essentially for my project, but its nice to have a realistic testing environment when possible.

Comment: @AlexCohen I agree... real data is better than test/example data any time. In this case, though, I think your only option is to wait for one to pop up.

Comment: you may use CW, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above answer, you can use either [EventBridge Scheduler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/what-is-scheduler.html) or [EventBridge Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-rules.html). It's better to use [EventBridge Scheduler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/what-is-scheduler.html). Then you can create a schedule and set the target as the [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function. In the [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function, you can code it to restart your instance(s).